# Dual monitor issue

Tags: delphi

I have a Windows application in Delphi 5.

I have two monitors. When my application runs, the parent is displayed on the first monitor. When I move the parent window to the second monitor and click a button, this child window stays on the first monitor. Is there a way to make the child window stay with the parent window no matter where the parent window is located? I searched related to this but solution is in C# not in Delphi, I am very new in Delphi. Child forms are creating at run time.

```
function BeforeCreateForm(Session:ISmSession;var IsDLL: Boolean):HWND;
var
  SmGUIServices: ISmGUIServices;
  MainWindowHandle:HWND;
begin
  MainWindowHandle:=0;
  IsDLL := false;
  if (Application.Handle = 0) and (Session <> nil) then
  begin
    IsDLL := true;
    SmGUIServices := (Session.Services.Item[TDM_SmarTeamServices[srvSmGUIService]] as ISmGUIServices);
    if SmGUIServices <> nil then
    {$IFNDEF BUILTPACKAGE}
       MainWindowHandle:=ForceIntegerToHwnd(SmGUIServices.MainWindowHandle);
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
  result:=MainWindowHandle;
end { of BeforeCreateForm } ;

procedure TSmForm.AfterCreateForm(Session:ISmSession; SmHelpContext:TDM_Int32; IsDLL: boolean);
begin

  if SmSession<>Session then
    SmSession:= Session;
  if SmHelpContext > 0 then
    HelpContext:=SmHelpContext;

  if (IsDLL) then
  begin
    if (Icon.Empty) and (ParentHWND <> 0) then
      SendMessage(Handle, WM_SETICON, 1, SendMessage(ParentHWND, WM_GETICON, 1, 0));
  end;
end { of TSmForm.AfterCreateForm } ;


constructor TSmForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent;Session:ISmSession;SmHelpContext:TDM_Int32);
var
  IsDLL: Boolean;
begin
  ParentHWND:=BeforeCreateForm(Session, IsDLL);
  HelpContext := 0;
  SmSession:= Session;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  AfterCreateForm(Session,SmHelpContext, IsDLL);
end;



procedure TSmForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);

var
  SmGuiServices: ISmGuiServices;
  MDIChild : TIMDIChildForm;
  MultiTabType :TDM_Int16;
  I:Integer;

begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  if ParentHWND <> 0 then
  begin
     Params.WndParent:=ParentHWND;

    SmGUIServices := (SmSession.Services.Item[TDM_SmarTeamServices[srvSmGUIService]] as ISmGUIServices);
    for I := SmGUIServices.SmViewWindows.Count - 1 downto 0 do
    begin
      if(SmGUIServices.SmViewWindows.item[I].SmView<>nil) then  
      if(SmGUIServices.SmViewWindows.item[I].SmView.ViewType <> vwtBomView) then       
      begin                                                                            
      MDIChild := TIMDIChildForm((SmGUIServices.SmViewWindows.item[I] as ISmRawViewWindow).SmViewWindowHandle);

      MultiTabType:=GetMultiTabType( MDIChild.tabSmView, MDIChild.tabSmView.ActivePage.PageIndex);

        if UpperCase(SmSession.ApplicationName) = 'MYAPP' then
        (MDIChild.MDIViewer.ViewerType = 10))) then  

        begin

         // Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
          Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
         Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;


          exit;
        end

        else
        begin
          if (MultiTabType = MT_Viewer) then
          begin
            Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TOPMOST;
            exit;
          end;
        end;

      end;                  
    end;   
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Re-read that a couple times and retracted my close vote. I misunderstood it. What I do understand is that if your main form is on some other monitor, and it opens another child form, you want that child form to open on the same monitor as its owner, correct?

Comment: You'll have to code this up against Win32 apis yourself. This is what happens when you use a 15 year old tool.

Comment: I don't know about Delphi 5, but in Delphi 10 Seattle, this behavior (as I assume) works as expected. When I open another form, it opens by default on the same monitor, no matter which monitor that is. The child form's `Position` property is also set to `poDefaultPosOnly` by default. Not sure how it is in Delphi 5.

Comment: If you set the `Position` property of the child form to `poOwnerFormCenter` then it should follow the owner form, please note that it depends on how you create the child form, show some code please.

Comment: yes, exact ally   @ Jerry Dodge

Comment: For that complex of code, I'm quite shocked you didn't include it in your original question. There's a lot going on there, and that has a huge effect on the outcome of your situation. As for solving the actual problem, this has become way over me. Your code seems to even have a DLL involved.

Comment: Gah! Don't make the desktop window be your window's owner. Pass 0.  Then you can remove WS_EX_APPWINDOW. Anyway, it seems you are already coding against Win32.  Just add some monitor aware code in there.

Comment: 1]Just add some monitor aware code ? what it is  exactly?                         2] Pass 0  where?

Comment: { this has become way over me.} @jerry Let me know please

Comment: I don't recall if D5 has the `DefaultMonitor` property; if it does, set it to `dmActiveForm`.

Comment: @user7424581 If you don't understand the code you posted, why are you attempting to work with it? It never ceases to amaze me that people don't realise when it is time to stop. Find whoever wrote this code and get them to bring you up to speed. Don't attempt to add more until you understand it. That is folly. It only ends one way, with you introducing more defects. If you don't understand something, you cannot proceed. It's that simple.

Comment: @CraigYoung is right though, Delphi 5 VCL does support multi-monitor. I remembered wrongly, I thought that came with Delphi 6. So if you do what he says then you should be good. However, your existing code is performing some pretty underhand actions, and might interfere with standard VCL behaviour.

Comment: Kindly,I know what code I write. I just can't get what you write. @David

Comment: I don't think so. You don't seem to understand your use of `GetDesktopWindow`. It looks like you don't really want to face up to matters.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic, based on the comments to the question, and @Craig's answer, it seems that the question is very far from complete.

Comment: please any one guide on this issue.

Comment: Uptill search on internet but no solution for this were found. So I thing there is no possible to open MDIChild on second monitor

Comment: @user7424581 How well do you understand the MDI framework? Do you understand that the MDI main form is supposed to serve as a container for MDI Child forms? Saying you want to show MDIChild "on second monitor" sounds like you don't want it inside the main MDI form; is that correct? If so, don't create that form as an MDI child; create it as a standalone form.

Comment: yes,Now I make those form  as a standalone form. but still it is not working.@CraigYoung

Comment: @user7424581 Have you considered and applied all the "things to note" in my answer? I've told you what you need to do. If it's not working it's because ***you did something wrong***. I cannot guess what you did wrong. Create a brand new simple app and test what I told you. It should work; if not then you need to post exactly what you did so your mistake can be identified. (Unless of course you don't really want a solution.)

Comment: actually i create one sample and it's working over there. but can't understand why it is not working in project.  [ SetWindowPos(Handle, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE or SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_NOZORDER or SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_FRAMECHANGED);   ] this method is use as much as i understand in this project. This project is created by my previous colleague i am new on this project and delphi also.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks David for confirming D5 does support [DefaultMonitor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.DefaultMonitor.).

If you set `DefaultMonitor` to `dmActiveForm` it should achieve what you're looking for. Note that the documentation specifies that your application must have a main form to work correctly. You'll also need to ensure that this setting does conflict with any of the other things you're doing.

Some things to note:

- By default, `DefaultMonitor` only kicks in the first time you show the form. After that `Position` is set to `poDesigned` to remember the form's position.
- If you want hide and re-show to appear on a different monitor, you'll have reset `TheForm.Postion := poScreenCenter;` or whichever option suits you best. Bear in mind that users may justifiably get annoyed by a form that doesn't 'recall' its position.
- Also note that the rules change substantially for MDI forms. If you're hacking around MDI forms without setting properties correctly *expect* strange behaviour.

Beyond this, I cannot advise you how to fix broken code if you don't actually show the broken code.

Comment: can you please give example how to use it. I tried this MDIChildren.DefaultMonitor:=dmActiveForm;

Comment: @user7424581 Ideally just set it in the `.dfm` of the form you're showing. I can't tell you what you're doing wrong because you haven't shown an [mcve]. You've provided some of the `TSmForm` code, but ***nothing*** about how you create or show the form. In fact, in spite of of your code _only implying_ you work with _other_ MDI forms, this comment is the first indication that `TSmForm` might itself be an MDI Child! If that's the case, then note that ***you are breaking default behaviour***. Because _by default_ MDI children always show on the main form.

Comment: I am creating those form at runtime

Comment: @user7424581 But of course. Just as you stated/demonstrated in your question.... ***No wait. You didn't !!*** _It is extremely rude and inconsiderate of you to waste people's time asking for help and not bothering to provide the relevant information up front._

Comment: and those which are created design time have already set this property.